# How do I activate this portal in the Mountain Ghost Town?

Tags: severed

I have all three powers, the rage arm, and all mementos. Can I activate this portal, between A & B, yet?

[image: map]

The red secret book seems to be related.

[image: page1]
[image: page2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m at 100% completion and that portal isn’t active. I don’t think it can be activated. I think that red book is a red herring or it had to do with the other portals.